How to scroll down the page when using orbitcontrols from react-three/drei?
I'm using react-tree/fiber , three, and react-three/drei to show a glb format file. The issue is i'm not able to scroll down to the other section of page if i'm on glb file section currently. Because in orbitcontrols based on scroll pinch in and out event is performed so how i will able to scroll down with this situation?
I have tried to customize the scroll event using scrollControls and also tried to unable the zoom using enableZoom property of orbitcontrols and many more things in addition.
What im expecting is if i reach any one min and max stage of zooming at that time it will stop zooming that is working as well but the section should scroll down. I should be able to scroll down the page after both conditions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
